# Create a background service in Windows Store Application

Tags: windows-store-apps, background-process

I'm new in development Windows Store applications but I have some experience in Android.

Is there any analog of [Android service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) in Windows Store Apps?

I need some service to run on a background, for example, service that writes to file some information when application is not active.

I read about [BackgroundTasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx) but it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Runtime was designed for maximum battery life so there are not any Windows Store "service" applications. The closest thing would be Background Tasks, which you have said will not  work for you.

From the MSDN Blog article [Being Productive When Your App Is Off Screen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/16/being-productive-when-your-app-is-offscreen.aspx):

The Windows Runtime does provide facilities for doing things in the background, such as:

- Background file download or upload
- Background audio
- Sharing
- Device data sync
- Live tiles
- Scheduled notifications
- Background tasks (mentioned above)

I would suggest taking a look at the above article and see if any of the listed things will work for you.